# dma_map_single and dma_map_page

Tags: intel, dma

I want to do dma of multiple frames to send a big frame( jumbo ). I am  able to send normal frame ( of size 1500  ). I need some doubts on dma.

1. What is real advantage of dma_map_single() over other api. We could do everything with dma_map_page , right ?
2. Suppose we need to transmit a big frame( jumbo ) in a driver , and i have stored this frame in multiple buffers. These buffers are not contiguous in physical memory or in virtual memory. But these buffers are in kernel space. How can we  send it as a  one frame. Should we use scatter-gather dma ?. Is this possible with other  dma_api ?

Answer (score 0):

1. dma_map_single and dma_map_page will eventually call
   dam_ops->map_page - the eventual function is decided by the arch and
   kernel config. usualy it will be intel_map_page on x86 machines with
   IOMMU.
2. First of all Jumbo frames from the kernels standpoint are irrelevant
   at TX time as the network stack coalesce transmitted buffers to up
   to 64K packets (LSO/TSO) and the NIC will eventually break the
   single 64K packet to several MTU(9K/1500 on ETH) sized packets each
   with its own L3 headers.

To your question the SKB can have a scatter-gather list - each buffer then dma-mapped.
The list of dma-addresses and buffer lengths is then written in a send descriptor to the NIC which knows how to combine them all together to be sent.

And by the way there is a dma_map_sg API for scatter lists in the Kernel and it will return a scatter list with a list of dma addresses. This is usually irrelevant to NIC drivers.